# samr analysis: How to interpret Median FDR/90th perc FDR=0.000000?

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am performing significance analysis of microarray (SAM) using the [samr](https://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/SAM/) package in R.

I have some doubts regarding the reported "Median FDR" and "90th perc FDR" values, as illustrated in the following:

```
samr.obj <- samr(data1,
            resp.type = "Two class unpaired",
            assay.type = "array",
            nperms=1000,
            center.arrays=TRUE,
            testStatistic = "standard",
            random.seed=42)
delta.table <- samr.compute.delta.table(samr.obj)
```

An excerpt of delta.table:

```
print(delta.table[,1:6])

      delta           #med false pos  #90th perc false pos #called median FDR 90th perc FDR
[22,] 0.869597977       1.0666667            2.400000       31 0.03440860    0.07741935
[23,] 0.954388709       0.8000000            2.133333       30 0.02666667    0.07111111
[24,] 1.043123196       0.2666667            1.333333       25 0.01066667    0.05333333
[25,] 1.135801439       0.0000000            0.000000        6 0.00000000    0.00000000
```

**My question**:

How to interpret line `[25, ]` having `"Median FDR"= 0.000000` and `"90th perc FDR"= 0.000000`? Is the corrected p-value "so small" it is actually rounded? Or should be considered an error?

Comment: cross-posted: https://www.biostars.org/p/427540/

Comment: It might be to do with printing methods, try `delta.table[25, 5]`.

Comment: @zx8754 I tried, but no way: I got a not so informative 0 value.